# How to obtain weight matrices during training on Scikit

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am training a MLPClassifier by using Scikit. Lets say I want to train for 5 epochs on MNIST with one hidden layer of 100 neurons.

If I do "mlp = MLPClassifier(...)" and then "mlp.fit(train,test)", then I can obtain the trained weights with "mlp.coefs_".

But what I want is the sequence of weight matrices obtained after each epoch during training. So if I train for 5 epochs I would want a list of size 5 with the history of weight matrices.

Is this possible with scikit? Or should I use Keras?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to train your model with a fraction of the epochs you wanted to do.

Store the parameters.

Then continue training your model with the warm_start = True parameter.  You would do this until you got the overall number of epochs you wanted.

In the context of sci-kit learns implementation the max_iter parameter would be the epochs.  This is referenced in this link.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284491/are-the-epochs-equivalent-to-the-iterations

Comment: Can you do this in Keras too?

Comment: I am not as familiar with Keras.  However it appears it has some sort of [callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/) functionality that might be what you are looking for.  Direct quote from the documentation.  _A callback is a set of functions to be applied at given stages of the training procedure. You can use callbacks to get a view on internal states and statistics of the model during training._